# I know `xpub`, but what are `ypub` and `zpub`?

Tags: terminology, xpub

I am familiar with the concept of extended pubkeys. However, I sometimes see mention of "ypub" and "zpub". Are they related to xpubs? If so, what is the difference? How are ypubs and zpubs standardized? Who uses them?